# jQuery multiple selectors with .val()

Tags: jquery

Consider:

```
$("[id^='txtYear_']").val();
```

Why is this only giving me the value entered in the first input box with an ID staring with "txtYear_"? I would like to get the values of all input boxes that have an ID that starts with "txtYear_".

Comment: `$("[id^='txtYear_']")` will return a collection of elements if you have more than one element that matches it. This means you will have to iterate through the collection :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[$.fn.val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) returns the value of the first element in the collection of found elements. If you want an array of values you can simply use [$.fn.map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) + [$.fn.get](http://api.jquery.com/get/):

```
var values = $("[id^='txtYear_']").map(function() {
  return this.value
}).get()
```

Note: `.get()` is necessary because $.fn.map doesn't return an array, but a new jQuery collection.

To check that all values are not empty (not `""`) you can do something like this with the help of [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
var allFilled = values.every(function(value) {
  return value.trim()
})
```

If you don't need auxiliary `values` array you can do it simpler:

```
var allFilled = $("[id^='txtYear_']").get().every(function(el) {
  return el.value.trim()
}) // => true/false
```

Comment: I would like to make sure that all of these values are not equal to "" (are not empty).  How do I transform this to return "true" or "false"? thanks!

Answer (score 3):

That's how val() works. You would have to loop over the elements in order to get all the values:

```
let vals = $("[id^='txtYear_']").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

```js
let vals = $("[id^='txtYear_']").map(function() {
   return $(this).val();
}).get();

console.log(vals);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtYear_1" value="1">
<input id="txtYear_2" value="2">
<input id="txtYear_3" value="3">
<input id="txtYear_4" value="4">
<input id="txtYear_5" value="5">
<input id="txtYear_6" value="6">
<input id="txtYear_7" value="7">
```

Or to know which is what, you could use an object:

```js
let vals = {};
$("[id^='txtYear_']").each(function() {
   vals[$(this).prop('id')] = $(this).val();
});

console.log(vals);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtYear_1" value="1">
<input id="txtYear_2" value="2">
<input id="txtYear_3" value="3">
<input id="txtYear_4" value="4">
<input id="txtYear_5" value="5">
<input id="txtYear_6" value="6">
<input id="txtYear_7" value="7">
```

Comment: So why suddenly clumsy usage of redundant array and push when you can just use $.fn.map?

Answer (score 1):

**Why only the first input?**

See on this link: http://api.jquery.com/val/

jQuery document said about `val()` method:

`Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the value of every matched element.`

**How to get the values of all input elements**

Please note that jQuery selector always returns an object which contains matched elements in an array property.
But you can access all matched element directly by `[]` operator like this

`$("[id^='txtYear_']")[0]`

`$("[id^='txtYear_']")[1]`

...

`$("[id^='txtYear_']")[n]`