# Jquery .val() with .reduce (knowing if all values are empty)

Tags: jquery

> $("[id^='txtYear_']").val();

How can I know if all input boxes with an ID starting with 'txtYear_'  are not empty (not equal to "")?

I'm not able to use `.reduce` with `.val()`.

thanks all!

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtYear_1" value="1">
<input id="txtYear_2" value="2">
<input id="txtYear_3" value="3">
<input id="txtYear_4" value="4">
<input id="txtYear_5" value="5">
<input id="txtYear_6" value="6">
<input id="txtYear_7" value="7">
```

**EDIT: Need ES5 (for IE11)**

Comment: Add a complete working example with the exact problem you have...

Comment: $("[id^='txtYear_']").reduce(function(total, current) {
  return this.value === "";
}).get();

doesn't work

Comment: Not in the comment, and you are missing the html. Update the question to have a working example...

Comment: It's just a follow-up of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45664348/jquery-multiple-selectors-with-val/45664446#45664446

Comment: It doesn't matter. When you ask a question make sure you have everything needed inside...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use plain js' `every` for that, not sure if jQuery has an equivalent.

```js
let allNotEmpty = Array.from($("[id^='txtYear_']")).every(function(e) {
  return e.value !== "";    
})

console.log(allNotEmpty);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtYear_1" value="1">
<input id="txtYear_2" value="2">
<input id="txtYear_3" value="3">
<input id="txtYear_4" value="4">
<input id="txtYear_5" value="5">
<input id="txtYear_6" value="6">
<input id="txtYear_7" value="7">
```

Comment: Sounds like what I want! However is this ES5 or ES6? I need a code that would also work in IE11

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [`filter`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) to reduce and [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to enumerate the filtered fields:

```js
$("[id^='txtYear_']").filter(function() {
    return $(this).val().length > 0;
}).each(function(i, el) {
    console.log($(this).val());
    $(this).css('border-color', 'green');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo" >
  <input id="txtYear_1" value="" size="50"/>
  <input id="txtYear_2" value="" size="50"/>
  <input id="txtYear_3" value="some_value" size="50"/>
</div>
```

Comment: will this return "false" ?

Comment: @Emilio this will filter and remove all input fields that their value is not of `length > 0`.

Comment: would it be possible to reduce it to a "true" or "false" value instead?

Comment: @Emilio if you mean to get all the fields that their text value is of `"true"` or `"false"` (string values), then yes, just change this line `return $(this).val().length > 0;` to this `return $(this).val() == "true";` to get all the fields that their value is set to `"true"`.